# Remove inputted char from String recursively in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a recursive function that takes a char as input, and removes the char from a string on output.

**Eg: INPUT: abbacysa | OUTPUT: bbcys**

I'm a beginner in Haskell so just trying to wrap my head around recursion still with practice.

I start out by creating the function with an empty list
I then select the elements within the list and begin the condition guard.
I looked into using drop but I think maybe there is a better way of doing this?

```
removeChar [] = []
removeChar (x:xs)
  | x `elem` "a" = removeChar drop "a"
```

Comment: `removeChar = filter (/= 'a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with base of recursion:

```
removeChar [] = []
```

If string is not empty, you have two possible options:

1. It starts from `a` then you want to skip. So result is just rest of string without letter `'a'`.

```
removeChar ('a':xs) = removeChar xs
```

2. It doesn't, then you want to keep it. So result is letter plus rest of string without letter `'a'`.

```
removeChar (x:xs) = x: removeChar xs
```

Comment: Don't you mean, "If string is _not_ empty"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where you put in a string and a char you want to remove from the string.

Recursively:

```
removeChar :: String -> Char -> String
removeChar [] _ = []
removeChar (x:xs) n = if (x == n) then removeChar xs n
                 else x : removeChar xs n
```

First we check that char "x" in string (x:xs) equals char "n", if it does then we remove the character, else we keep on looping through the string.

```
Input: removeChar "abba baby" 'b'
Output: "aa ay"
```